How to avoid Unhandled Runtime Error in next.js app router
I am getting run time error in next.js app router.

This error can be resolved by restarting the server or clearing the cache. However, it may persist, which can be frustrating. What causes this error, and how can it be effectively fixed in a Next.js app router?
